# Eliminating Entries Based On Revision

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I need to figure out how to eliminate older revisions from my query's results, my database stores orders as 'Q000000' and revisions have an appended '-number'.  My query currently is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Estimate.EstimateNo
FROM Estimate 
INNER JOIN EstimateDetails ON EstimateDetails.EstimateID = Estimate.EstimateID
INNER JOIN EstimateDoorList ON EstimateDoorList.ItemSpecID = EstimateDetails.ItemSpecID
WHERE (Estimate.SalesRepID = '67' OR Estimate.SalesRepID = '61') AND Estimate.EntryDate >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND EstimateDoorList.SlabSpecies LIKE '%MDF%'
ORDER BY Estimate.EstimateNo
```

So for instance, the results would include:

```
Q120455-10
Q120445-11
Q121675-2
Q122361-1
Q123456
Q123456-1
```

From this, I need to eliminate 'Q120455-10' because of the presence of '-11' for that order, and 'Q123456' because of the presence of the '-1' revision.  I'm struggling greatly with figuring out how to do this, my immediate thought was to use case statements but I'm not sure what is the best way to implement them and how to filter.  Thank you in advance, let me know if any more information is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to parse your `EstimateNo` column into sequence number and revision number using [CHARINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql) and [SUBSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql) (or [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) in newer versions) and [CAST/CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) the revision to a numeric type

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(Estimate.EstimateNo,0,CHARINDEX('-',Estimate.EstimateNo)) as [EstimateNo], 
CAST(SUBSTRING(Estimate.EstimateNo,CHARINDEX('-',Estimate.EstimateNo)+1, LEN(Estimate.EstimateNo)-CHARINDEX('-',Estimate.EstimateNo)+1) as INT) as [EstimateRevision]
FROM
...
```

You can then use

1. [APPLY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) - to select TOP 1 row that matches the EstimateNo or
2. [Window function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql) such as [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) to select only records with row number of 1

For example, using a ROW_NUMBER would look something like below:

```
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EstimateNo ORDER BY EstimateRevision DESC) AS "LastRevisionForEstimate",
-- rest of the needed columns
FROM
(
-- query above goes here
)
```

You can then wrap the query above in a simple select with a where predicate filtering out a specific value of LastRevisionForEstimate, for instance

```
SELECT --needed columns
FROM -- result set above
WHERE LastRevisionForEstimate = 1
```

Please note that this is to a certain extent, **pseudocode**, as I do not have your schema and cannot test the query

If you dislike the nested selects, check out the [Common Table Expressions](https://www.google.pl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjeqJni99jTAhXK1hQKHZyzAr8QFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftechnet.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fms190766(v%3Dsql.105).aspx&usg=AFQjCNFsIau0vrmyRfFvMnYai4EyPHlQDg&sig2=iyQdvH8EvFuXUqo-QhuQBQ)

Comment: Thank you for the very in depth explanation, this seems like it will work perfectly.